# How to copy files from a network share to SharePoint each day?

Tags: 2007, copy-and-paste

I have a need to copy files placed in a network location into a SharePoint document library each morning.

I've tried to do this with a batch file that uses xcopy to copy from the shared drive, to SharePoint, like so;

```
xcopy "\\networkdrive\Files and Folders" "\\sharepoint\re\KC\System Report\" /Y
```

Unfortunately this throws the error:

> File creation error - The directory is not empty.
>
> Unable to create directory - \sharepoint\re\KC\System Report\ 0
>   File(s) copied

Is there a reason for this I can correct and if not what would be the best way to automate this process?

Comment: If you run a script directly on the `\\sharepoint` server shuld you not be able to read files from `\\networkdrive` and upload them to a document library using either a PS script (not sure how in 2007) or a simple C# program and have this run in scheduled task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add *.* to the source like this:

```
xcopy "\\networkdrive\Files and Folders\*.*" "\\sharepoint\re\KC\System Report\" /Y
```

This will copy the files in the directory instead of the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via xcopy, we've done it in the past. The sharepoint location should be mapped with the webdav address and be executed with a user account that has contribute permissions to the library.